# How to add a delay to a sound being played with swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uiimageview, delay

I am a total swift beginner and am working on a tutorial project (magic 8 ball) and have been successful at doing the following:
- play a specific sound when the "Ask" button is pressed. 
- play a specific sound when for each of the randomly picked images

However now the sound that should play whenever the button is pressed only plays once and from there on i only hear the sounds that are being displayed with each image. Is this because I am "stuck" in the "if - else" loop ? Or do I have to delay the sounds that are being played for each image in the array ?

Thanks so much for your help !

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var magicBall: UIImageView!

    var magicBallDisplay = 1
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      magicBall.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "theanswerisyes")

    }

    @IBAction func askButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let magicBallArray = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "askagainlater"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "no"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "theanswerisyes"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "yes"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "noidea")]
        magicBall.image = magicBallArray.randomElement()

        let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Ask", ofType: "wav")!)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        }catch {
            print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()

        if (magicBall.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "yes")))! {

            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yes", ofType: "mp3")!)
            do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

            } catch {
            print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
            }
             audioPlayer.play()
        }
        else if (magicBall.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "no")))! {
            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "no", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        } catch {
        print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
         audioPlayer.play()
        }
        else if (magicBall.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "theanswerisyes")))! {
            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "theanswerisyes", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        } catch {
        print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
         audioPlayer.play()
        }
        else if (magicBall.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "noidea")))! {
            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "noidea", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        } catch {
        print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
         audioPlayer.play()
        }
        else if (magicBall.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "askagainlater")))! {
            let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "askagainlater", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        } catch {
        print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
         audioPlayer.play()
        }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a new project and change your code to this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var magicBall: UIImageView!
    // you never used this
    //var magicBallDisplay = 1
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        magicBall.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "theanswerisyes")
    }

    @IBAction func askButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // because you have audio file and image with equal name i made array of string
        let magicBallArray = [ "yes","no","theanswerisyes","noidea","askagainlater"]
        // check if i get not null item
        guard let choosedImageName = magicBallArray.randomElement() else {return}
        print(choosedImageName)
        // set image with random picked name
        magicBall.image = UIImage(named: choosedImageName)
        // play ask sound
        playSound(fileName: "Ask", fileType: "wav")
        // play picked image sound after 10 second from now()
        // change number to your needed time
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
            self.playSound(fileName: choosedImageName, fileType: "mp3")
        })
    }

    private func playSound(fileName: String, fileType: String)
    {
        // check if you find the audio file
        guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType) else {
            print("path not found")
            return
        }
        // make NSURL from path
        let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        } catch {
            print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

I explain code for you.
I didn't enable the button. you can improve this code when you came stronger in swift

Comment: ImanMF - thank you very much for going trough the trouble of explaining this to me. Now it es very clear how I can tackle this and I will be able to use this in the future. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarcBaier swift has nullability and you must practice this with if and guard statement.

Answer (score 0):

your code is really messy.
at first, I advise you to make a function for playing sound like that:

```
func playSound(fileName: String, fileType: String) {

       let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName,     ofType: fileType)!)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL as URL)

        }catch {
            print("there was some error. The error was \(error)")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
}
```

you must have a callback for first play sound. after finishing the first sound you can check your if-else or you can try switch-case.

also, you can use delay for playing second sound

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip. As I am a beginner I don't really know which parts would be replaced with this new function. How do I set it up so that the new "playSound" function calls / plays the correct / corresponding sound ?